# Showing new lines <br> in the browser when having \n in the database

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, express, ejs

In mongo I have a document with a field like `reviewText: 'this is line 1\nthis is line 2',` . I got that from a `textarea` so the `\n` is there because the user hit enter. I want to print the text on the screen in a div with a line break (preferably only one line break if he hits many enters) I don't know how to do that I dont get on the screen any `\n`s

I do `<div class = "displayReview"><%= e.reviewText %></div>` in EJS that just prints it all on oneline. It gets me `<div class="displayReview">this is line 1 this is line 2</div>` in the browser.

I have someplace in my routes that updates the docs like:

```
    .then(function(returnedReviews){
        console.log(" returnedReview ",returnedReviews);
        returnedReviews.forEach(function(e){
            e.momented = moment(e.createdAt.getTime()).fromNow()
            // e.reviewText = e.reviewText.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />')
        })
```

I tried to do what I have in the comments. but that obviously just put `<br />` (the text) in the string and not HTML. I was hoping there was an easy way to do this.

I want to see line breaks when it gets printed to the screen where the user hits enter in the `textarea` before he sent the form. If the user hits the enter button multiple times in a row there should be only one line break.

Comment: I read that in the source code you could see the line breaks . and you could use `white-space: pre;` to see the spaces but that is not what I want. One problem is that you could see the spaces where users hits a lot of spaces.

Answer (score 5):

First, standardize the newline characters and reduce them to just one (in keeping with your requirements):

```
e.reviewText = e.reviewText.replace(/\r?\n/g, '\n');
e.reviewText = e.reviewText.replace(/\n+/g, '\n');
```

This puts your data in a standard form. Displaying that data in a particular way is the job of your template. I haven't used EJS, but looking at their sample code it looks like something along these lines should work:

```
<div class = "displayReview">
  <% e.reviewText.split('\n').forEach(function(ln) {%>
     <%= ln %><br>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

In this particular case, perhaps after the template renders the data the data itself is thrown away, so being particular about separating data-manipulation from presentation is a formality, but it's still a good habit and makes the code easier to modify later.

Comment: Oh, too late! I was coding the same example. +1 for you.

Comment: Works great, seems it's only missing a closing ')'

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth mentioning that JavaScript isn't strictly required to achieve this (except if the user hits the enter button multiple times in a row there will be multiple line breaks), if you have the capability to modify the CSS for .displayReview.

This can be achieved by changing the white-space property to be pre, pre-line, or pre-wrap.

Example:

```
.displayReview {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), the differences between pre, pre-line, and pre-wrap are

#### pre

```
Sequences of whitespace are preserved, lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at <br> elements.
```

#### pre-wrap

```
Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at <br>, and as necessary to fill line boxes.
```

#### pre-line

```
Sequences of whitespace are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at <br>, and as necessary to fill line boxes.
```